# getting new data from a json file using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have an android java app and i need some data from a json file so i used volley to get data from json
my problem is when i change data on the json file i should uninstall the app and install it again then get the new data otherwise it keeps the old data even after killing it from ram

```
   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, LINK, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


        try {

            JSONArray jsonArrayVariabls = response.getJSONArray("variables");
            JSONObject var = jsonArrayVariabls.getJSONObject(0);
            Variables.name = var.getString("name");
            Variables.adresse=var.getString("adresse");
            
                     callBack.onSuccess();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});

jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: because you are not using live data that's why it happen do live data mvvm architecture it will update it

Comment: i'm storing the data in a staic variables at the spash screen so need the data from json only when i open the app

Comment: Instead of static variable. access from Application class

Comment: you mean create a class the store data in a list and use DAO ?

Comment: but the problem here is when i reopen the app the code above is executing but i'm still getting the old values even when logging the var.getString("name") i'm getting the old data

Comment: Solved the problem by adding this line of code 
 requestQueue.getCache().clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from cache so you need to clear it before request using this line

```
        requestQueue.getCache().clear();
```